# Corregir este error en NodeJs

Tags: nodejs

A la hora de consumir una api para el inicio de sesión me aparece este error en mi consola cuando me voy a loguear

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y tambien en la imagen me aparece un error en la siguiente fracción de código

```
 Routes.forEach(route => {
    (app as any)[route.method](route.route, (route.roles.length > 0) ? [authenticateToken, checkRole(route.roles)] : [] , (req: Request, res: Response, next: Function) => {
        const result = (new (route.controller as any))[route.action](req, res, next);
        if (result instanceof Promise) {
            result.then(result => result !== null && result !== undefined ? res.send(result) : undefined);
        } else if (result !== null && result !== undefined) {
            res.json(result);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Tu código está muy parametrizado. Por otro lado, el error en principio indica que no estás capturando correctamente el error al usar una Promesa. Se ve que usas `then` pero no se ve que uses `catch`. Empieza por capturar los errores adecuadamente. Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Como marca el error, es una estructura circular, es decir, un objeto recursivo.

No hay que hacer `JSON.stringify` a objetos recursivos.

Estos objetos tienen dentro una propiedad que se referencia a la propiedad de jerarquía superior.

Ejemplo:

```js
var objeto = {}
objeto.propiedad = objeto
```

Al hacer `JSON.stringify` detecta que dentro del objeto hay una propiedad que referencia al mismo objeto, y por eso tira el error circular.